# jquery conflict with js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, conflict

welcome all ,

i have a problem with my images slider , it runs successfuly until poll script excuted then it stops , tried to combine both scripts didn't work also tried to use noConflict but in stops both of them .

this is the slider

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.s3Slider = function (vars) {
        var element = this;
        var timeOut = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000;
        var current = null;
        var timeOutFn = null;
        var faderStat = true;
        var mOver = false;
        var items = $("#sliderContent .sliderImage");
        var itemsSpan = $("#sliderContent .sliderImage span");
        items.each(function (i) {
            $(items[i]).mouseover(function () {
                mOver = true
            });
            $(items[i]).mouseout(function () {
                mOver = false;
                fadeElement(true)
            })
        });
        var fadeElement = function (isMouseOut) {
                var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut / 2) : timeOut;
                thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut;
                if (items.length > 0) {
                    timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut)
                } else {
                    console.log("Poof..")
                }
            };
        var makeSlider = function () {
                current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length - 1)];
                var currNo = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1;
                currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
                var newMargin = $(element).width() * currNo;
                if (faderStat == true) {
                    if (!mOver) {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut / 6), function () {
                            if ($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css("bottom") == 0) {
                                $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut / 6), function () {
                                    faderStat = false;
                                    current = items[currNo];
                                    if (!mOver) {
                                        fadeElement(false)
                                    }
                                })
                            } else {
                                $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut / 6), function () {
                                    faderStat = false;
                                    current = items[currNo];
                                    if (!mOver) {
                                        fadeElement(false)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!mOver) {
                        if ($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css("bottom") == 0) {
                            $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut / 6), function () {
                                $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut / 6), function () {
                                    faderStat = true;
                                    current = items[(currNo + 1)];
                                    if (!mOver) {
                                        fadeElement(false)
                                    }
                                })
                            })
                        } else {
                            $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut / 6), function () {
                                $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut / 6), function () {
                                    faderStat = true;
                                    current = items[(currNo + 1)];
                                    if (!mOver) {
                                        fadeElement(false)
                                    }
                                })
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        makeSlider()
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and this is the poll script

```
window.onload = function() {
$(".sidePollCon").load("ar_poll.html", function(r, s, xhr) {

    if (s == "error") {
        $(".sidePollCon").load("poll.html");


    } else {
        $(".vote_booroo").html("صوت الان");
        $(".viewresults").html("شاهد النتيجة");
        $("fieldset p").html("");
        $(".results_booroo p").html("");
        $(".result_booroo").attr("src", "../images/poll_color.jpg");

    }

});

};
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Use firebug to see if there is a javascript error.

Comment: While waiting ... no conflict does not fix your javascript errors. ;-) see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Does the poll script work without the slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential problem could be the `window.onload` assignment. It is very prone to conflict.

Every time you do `window.onload =` the previous assignemnt will be overridden. See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLzzj/):

The output shows that the first `window.onload` assignment never gets called, while the jQuery alternative does get called.

`jQuery.noConflict` does little in this regard. All it does is to prevent override the `$` symbol so that another lib can use it.

So if you are also using the `window.onload` event to invoke the slider, then you have conflict. You can easily solve this problem by using the jquery format:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    ...
});
```

However usually you would tie the event to `$(document).load(function(){...});` or in short form: `$(function(){...})`.

So for your poll that would be:

```
$(function(){
    $(".sidePollCon").load("ar_poll.html", function(r, s, xhr) {

        if (s == "error") {
            $(".sidePollCon").load("poll.html");


        } else {
            $(".vote_booroo").html("صوت الان");
            $(".viewresults").html("شاهد النتيجة");
            $("fieldset p").html("");
            $(".results_booroo p").html("");
            $(".result_booroo").attr("src", "../images/poll_color.jpg");

        }

    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: noConflict stops both of the scripts , tried the other event to invoke both methods but the the problem still exist ,

Comment: @mgamal the only way that can happen is when you have a fatal error. Please post that error, otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

resolving conflicts in jquery (possibly with another JS library .. like script.aculo.us) can be resolved using noconflict()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

$.noConflict();

but make sure that u have no error in your javascript code itself. use firebug and 
console.log('') to test your script.